# how to convert from String to enum during BeanUtils.copyProperties in Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, enums, dto

I have to copy the properties from dto to entity class.
I am using BeanUtils.copyProperties().

In request body I am sending like below:

```
{
"userName":"test",
"userStatus": "I",
}
```

**DTO class:**

```
public class UserDto {
    private String userName;
    private String userStatus;

    public User buildUser() {
        User user = new User();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, user);

        return user;
    }
}
```

**Entity class:**

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "user_status")
    private UserStatus userStatus;

}
```

**note:** userStatus can be nullable field in table.

Service code:

```
User user = userDto.buildUser();
```

I am getting userStatus value as null in User entity class.

When I changed UserDto.userStatus to enum type, then request body is not accepting empty value.

How do I convert from String to enum during BeanUtils.copyProperties() ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring `BeanUtils` is not designed for such customizations.
You should set the field manually with.
While MapStruct or Dozen are.

As alternative to keep `BeanUtils` and no explicit setter invocation you have :

- defining a factory method for the enum Jackson processing (a static method annotated `@JsonCreator` in the enum class such as :

`@JsonCreator public static UserStatus getValue(String name) {

      return 
      Stream.of(UserStatus.values())
            .findAny(s -> s.name().equals(name))
            .orElse(null);
}`

In most of cases, this is the best solution  as it handles the issue at the root.

- setting the flag to ignore unknown value for any field of the class:

`public class UserDto {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
       //...
}`

Fastest solution but I don't like a lot as it may hide some other serialization/deserialization issues.

- adding an enum value representing the emptiness. You could so define the enum in the DTO.
  In order to not store it in the database,  the mapping of this enum value to `null` should be done in the entity itself.
  For example :

`public void setUserStatus(UserStatus userStatus){
        if (userStatus != UserStatus.EMPTY){
            this.userStatus = userStatus;
        }
}`

It should work but I am not a big fan either...

Answer (score 0):

Enums cannot be `null` because their underlining values are `int` but you can set the **FIRST value** in the `enum` as a default value. tyou can also define your field in DTO as an Enum type instead of String.

**UserStatus**

```
public enum UserStatus {
    NULL,
    ACTIVE,
    INACTIVE;

}
```

Service code:

```
userDto.setUserStatus(UserStatus.NULL);
userDto.buildUser();
```

OR If you want to  set this override of `copyProperties` method to ignore `userStatus` field while converting:

```
 public static void copyProperties(Object source, Object target,
                                   @Nullable Class<?> editable,
                                   @Nullable String... ignoreProperties);
```

Comment: If I ignore the field how it will be converted to enum value ?